# How to add a UIView as SuperView(background View) to already existed UI elemets with contraints

Tags: ios, swift

firstly I have Placed 3 labels in the xib file and I added constraints to the elements(using the Auto layout in storyboard), next I got the requirement to add an image to its background so to do this first I need to remove those constraints after that I added UIImageView and finally need to set constraints to all UI elements but if I have more UI elements with more constraints its more difficult to remove constraint and adding view how to solve this issue

Comment: Is it really necessary to remove all the existing UI elements to add a background `UIImageView` to the existing `UIView` hierarchy? 

I would consider adding the background `UIImageView` to the parent of the `UILabel` instances instead. The background would be initially on top. Then using interface builder you can re-order the background so that it is behind the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its hard to implement when information is poor when you begin. To solve this particular problem, you could have a transparent container view. Just make UIView, place your Elements on it and add constraints. When you now have to add another view behind it, you just have to remove the constraints from the container. Makes things easier.

Another thing is, you can leave those constraints as they are. They refer to the view you have put the Elements in. When you now add another view behind them, you just can add constraints to this new view and the other elements are not affected.

Hope that halps a bit!